# SceneKit camera, how to compensate for euler rules (orientation) changes

Tags: ios, macos, camera, scenekit

Maybe this is more of a math question, but I am hoping somebody can help me understand how I would compensate for changes to my camera's orientation.

What I would like to do is to be able to move my camera around the scene using game-like controls. I have W S A D keys set up to move the camera forward, backward, left and right respectively. I do this by changing the values of the camera node's position vector.  I also have the right left up and down arrow keys mapped to turning and tilting the camera. I do this by adjusting the camera node's euler rules (pitch and yaw).

Things work well until I turn the camera with the right and left arrows. Pressing W after this moves the camera in the direction it was facing before I applied yaw to it. The behavior makes sense to me, but I cannot figure out what I need to do to my position-vector tweaking to compensate for the yaw I've applied.

Do I need to multiply my position vector somehow by new transform?  Or better yet is there some other property like the pivot that I can change, so that I can keep my position code the same?

Thanks for any pointers.

---

Update here is the code I'm working with so far:

```
public func displayTimerDidFire(timer: MyCustomDisplayTimer!) {
    if timer === cameraMoveTimer {

        var cameraTransform = cameraNode.transform
        var x = CGFloat(0.0)
        var y = CGFloat(0.0)
        var z = CGFloat(0.0)

        var step : CGFloat = 10.0

        if moveUpKeyDown {
            y += step
        }
        if moveDownKeyDown {
            y -= step
        }
        if moveLeftKeyDown {
            x -= step
        }
        if moveRightKeyDown {
            x += step
        }
        if moveForwardKeyDown {
            z -= step
        }
        if moveBackwardKeyDown {
            z += step
        }

        cameraTransform = SCNMatrix4Translate(cameraTransform, x, y, z)
        cameraNode.transform = cameraTransform
    }
    else if timer === cameraTiltTimer {
        var angles = cameraNode.eulerAngles
        var stepAngle : CGFloat = CGFloat(M_PI_2 / 90.0)

        if turnLeftKeyDown {
            angles.y += stepAngle
        }
        if turnRightKeyDown {
            angles.y -= stepAngle
        }
        if tiltForwardKeyDown {
            angles.x -= stepAngle
        }
        if tiltBackwardKeyDown {
            angles.x += stepAngle
        }

        cameraNode.eulerAngles = angles
    }
}
```

I have two timers, one that updates the cameras position, and the other that updates its orientation.

The part I'm stuck on is that I know my new transform (old position plus the move increment from A S D W), and I know the camera's rotation, but I don't know how to combine those two into my true new transform. Transform is a SCNMatrix4, and rotation is a SCNVector4.

---

Update 2

Here is a reworked version of the code. I switched to working with the transform instead. I still cannot find the right manipulation to account for the rotation however.

```
public func displayTimerDidFire(timer: MyDisplayTimer!) {
    var cameraTransform = cameraNode.transform
    var x = CGFloat(0.0)
    var y = CGFloat(0.0)
    var z = CGFloat(0.0)

    var step : CGFloat = 10.0

    if moveUpKeyDown {
        y += step
    }
    if moveDownKeyDown {
        y -= step
    }
    if moveLeftKeyDown {
        x -= step
    }
    if moveRightKeyDown {
        x += step
    }
    if moveForwardKeyDown {
        z -= step
    }
    if moveBackwardKeyDown {
        z += step
    }

    cameraTransform = SCNMatrix4Translate(cameraTransform, x, y, z)
    // Do something with the transform to compensate for rotation..
    // ???

    cameraNode.transform = cameraTransform

    var angles = cameraNode.eulerAngles
    var stepAngle : CGFloat = CGFloat(M_PI_2 / 90.0)

    if turnLeftKeyDown {
        angles.y += stepAngle
    }
    if turnRightKeyDown {
        angles.y -= stepAngle
    }
    if tiltForwardKeyDown {
        angles.x -= stepAngle
    }
    if tiltBackwardKeyDown {
        angles.x += stepAngle
    }

    cameraNode.eulerAngles = angles
   // printNode(cameraNode)
}
```

---

Last Update

Thanks for the suggestions. Here is the implementation that is working for me

I needed this objc helper, as some of these functions to not seem to be available in Swift:

```
@implementation MySceneKitUtils
+ (SCNVector3)position:(SCNVector3)position multipliedByRotation:(SCNVector4)rotation
{
    if (rotation.w == 0) {
        return position;
    }
    GLKVector3 gPosition = SCNVector3ToGLKVector3(position);
    GLKMatrix4 gRotation = GLKMatrix4MakeRotation(rotation.w, rotation.x, rotation.y, rotation.z);
    GLKVector3 r = GLKMatrix4MultiplyVector3(gRotation, gPosition);
    return SCNVector3FromGLKVector3(r);
}
@end
```

And the implementation

```
public func displayTimerDidFire(timer: MyDisplayTimer!) {
    var x = CGFloat(0.0)
    var y = CGFloat(0.0)
    var z = CGFloat(0.0)

    var step : CGFloat = 10.0

    if moveUpKeyDown {
        y += step
    }
    if moveDownKeyDown {
        y -= step
    }
    if moveLeftKeyDown {
        x -= step
    }
    if moveRightKeyDown {
        x += step
    }
    if moveForwardKeyDown {
        z -= step
    }
    if moveBackwardKeyDown {
        z += step
    }

    var cameraTransform = cameraNode.transform
    var rotation = cameraNode.rotation
    var rotatedPosition = MySceneKitUtils.position(SCNVector3Make(x, y, z), multipliedByRotation: cameraNode.rotation)
    cameraTransform = SCNMatrix4Translate(cameraTransform, rotatedPosition.x, rotatedPosition.y, rotatedPosition.z)

    cameraNode.transform = cameraTransform

    // The rotation

    cameraTransform = cameraNode.transform
    var stepAngle = CGFloat(0.05)
    if turnLeftKeyDown {
        cameraTransform = SCNMatrix4Rotate(cameraTransform, stepAngle, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    }
    if turnRightKeyDown {
        cameraTransform = SCNMatrix4Rotate(cameraTransform, -stepAngle, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    }
    if tiltForwardKeyDown {
        cameraTransform = SCNMatrix4Rotate(cameraTransform, stepAngle, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    }
    if tiltBackwardKeyDown {
        cameraTransform = SCNMatrix4Rotate(cameraTransform, -stepAngle, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    }

    cameraNode.transform = cameraTransform
}
```

Comment: post your code, sounds like a simple mistake in hie you apply transformations from input to camera

Comment: Updated with code example. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if `t` is the translation you compute from the WSAD keys, then you should not simply add it (`node.position += t`) but first apply a rotation and then add it : `node.position += node.rotation * t`

Comment: Thanks @mnuages. I think this is what I was trying to do conceptually, but I am not sure how to implement that. How do you multiply a node's position by its rotation? The position is a SCNVector3 and the rotation is a SCNVector4. I don't see anything in SceneKit or GLKit to do that. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm I've also tried working with the node's transform (a SCNMatrix4) and it's rotation (SCNVector4). But again I don't see any way to use these two to produce a new SCNMatrix4 I can apply to my transform property.

Comment: you can use `GLKMatrix4MakeRotation` to create a rotation matrix from the node's `rotation` (beware that `GLKMatrix4MakeRotation` takes `angle,x,y,z` and `rotation` gives `x,y,z,angle`), then use `GLKMatrix4MultiplyVector3` to multiply your translation by the rotation matrix

Comment: Hi @mnuages, sorry to add a post here, I have the same issue, but I have some trouble to make it work, I posted a question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32167131/how-to-rotate-a-character-and-make-him-always-go-forward-using-a-joystick-in-sce .Could you have a look? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My answer is add on to the above answer. I have used this for Pinch zoom.

```
            //Creating unit vector
            let unitVector = GLKVector4Make(0, 0, -1, 1)
            //converting tranform matrix
            let glktranform =  SCNMatrix4ToGLKMatrix4(cameraNode.transform)
            //multiply unit vector with transform matrix
            let rotatedMatrix = GLKMatrix4MultiplyVector4(glktranform, unitVector)

            //scale it with translation you compute from the WSAD key

            let finalScaledVector = GLKVector4MultiplyScalar(rotatedMatrix, translation)

            cameraNode.position.x = finalScaledVector.x
            cameraNode.position.y = finalScaledVector.y
            cameraNode.position.z = finalScaledVector.z
```

Hopefully this helps.