# move a camera toward it pointing direction taking rotation into consideration

Tags: ios, vector, 3d, camera, scenekit

lets say we have a scene with objects located in different xyz positions and rotations. 
one of the nodes is a camera which I want to move toward an imaginary point e.g center of screen(512, 384) backward or forward. by center of screen I mean center of a direction of a camera, so its what the user can see. the problems I'm facing currently are:

1. imaginary point (512, 384) is in 2D and how to convert that to 3D
2. how to move the camera forward/backward taking rotation into
   consideration

for instance, the camera has current location (x,y,z)(140, 199, 20) and is rotated around its axis (x,y,z)(25°, 187°, 301°). so how to move the camera toward its pointing direction.
I'm learning scene kit (incl. new to 3D) and any example/pseudo code is much appreciated.

my efforts till now only moves the camera toward root node.

```
    [_cameraNode runAction:[SCNAction moveTo:SCNVector3Make(_cameraNode.presentationNode.position.x, _cameraNode.presentationNode.position.y, _cameraNode.presentationNode.position.z - 5) duration:1]];
```

Comment: you should find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27738794/scenekit-camera-how-to-compensate-for-euler-rules-orientation-changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according @mnuages comment I could take the necessary code out and achieve what i asked for. thank you!

```
-(SCNVector3)position:(SCNVector3)position multipliedByRotation:(SCNVector4)rotation
{
   if (rotation.w == 0)
   {
       return position;
   }
   GLKVector3 gPosition = SCNVector3ToGLKVector3(position);
   GLKMatrix4 gRotation = GLKMatrix4MakeRotation(rotation.w, rotation.x, rotation.y, rotation.z);
   GLKVector3 r = GLKMatrix4MultiplyVector3(gRotation, gPosition);
   return SCNVector3FromGLKVector3(r);
 }

-(SCNMatrix4)moveCamera
{
   CGFloat step = 2.0
   CGFloat x = 0.0;
   CGFloat y = 0.0;
   CGFloat z = _touchCount == 2 ? -step : _touchCount == 1 ? step : 0.0;

   SCNMatrix4 cameraTransform = _cameraNode.transform;

   SCNVector3 rotatedPosition = [self position:SCNVector3Make(x, y, z) multipliedByRotation: _cameraNode.rotation];
   cameraTransform = SCNMatrix4Translate(cameraTransform, rotatedPosition.x, rotatedPosition.y, rotatedPosition.z);

    return cameraTransform;
}
```

Comment: This really helped me, thank you!