# How can I zoom a camera in the direction it is facing?

Tags: swift, matrix, 3d, camera, scenekit

I am making a 3d game in swift using scenekit. I have a pinch gesture recognizer so that the user can zoom in/out when they pinch.

I can easily access the current x,y,z coordinates as well as the rotation around each axis.

My problem is actually working out where to move my camera to.

At first I spent some time working it out with trig but I had trouble coming up with a generic solution that worked in all cases. I now believe the solution to lies in matrices. However, I'm unsure of the precise way to implement them.

For instance calling the rotational matrix on every call to my pinch handler function will obviously be bad and make my camera spin around like crazy.

**For convenience I have linked apples reference for SCNNode and scene matrices:**

[SCNNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNNode_Class/index.html)

[Scenekit Matrices and vectors](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SceneKit_Functions/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See answers here : [SceneKit camera, how to compensate for euler rules (orientation) changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27738794/scenekit-camera-how-to-compensate-for-euler-rules-orientation-changes)

Note that changing the camera's FOV affects perspective and objects will appear very distorted at some point. Moving the camera closer to these objects solves this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Don't move the camera, just change either its `xFov` and `yFov` properties:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNCamera_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNCamera/yFov

Comment: That has the effect of distorting nodes.  Moving the camera is better.